# Pass heap-based N-ary array reference to function

Tags: c++, arrays, templates

I am trying to pass an N-ary array to a function in C++.

Keeping it simple, for a 1D array, here's a :

```
#include <iostream>

template <size_t N> int sign(int(&arr)[N], int i)
{
    return (arr[i] >= 0) ? +1 : -1 ;
}

int main(int argn, char** argv)
{
    const int SIZE = 2;

    int (*arr1d) = new int[SIZE];
    arr1d[0] = 12;
    arr1d[1] = -1;

    std::cout << "sign 0 : " << sign(arr1d, 0) << std::endl ;     
    std::cout << "sign 1 : " << sign(arr1d, 1) << std::endl ;
}
```

But this won't compile:

```
Sign.cpp:17:50: error: no matching function for call to ‘sign(int*&, int)’
     std::cout << "sign 1 : " << sign(arr1d, 1) << std::endl ;
                                              ^
Sign.cpp:3:29: note: candidate: template<long unsigned int N> int sign(int (&)[N], int)
 template <size_t N> int sign(int(&arr)[N], int i)
                         ^~~~
Sign.cpp:3:29: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
Sign.cpp:17:50: note:   mismatched types ‘int [N]’ and ‘int*’
     std::cout << "sign 1 : " << sign(arr1d, 1) << std::endl ;
```

I don't mind *not* using templates (which seems to be the problem here).

Any suggestion?

---

Same error for the 2D case:

```
#include <iostream>

template <size_t M, size_t N> int sign(int(&arr)[M][N], int i, int j)
{
    return (arr[i][j] >= 0) ? +1 : -1 ;
}

int main(int argn, char** argv)
{
    const int SIZE = 2;

    int (*arr2d)[SIZE] = new int[SIZE][SIZE];                           
    arr2d[0][0] = 12;
    arr2d[0][1] = -1;
    arr2d[1][0] = 32;
    arr2d[1][1] = -4;

    std::cout << "sign 0 1: " << sign(arr2d, 0, 1) << std::endl ;
}
```

---

Comment: arr1d is not an array. it's a pointer to the first element of an array.

Comment: try having your function take such a pointer as parameter, instead of an array.

Comment: Since it's templates and clearly c++, don't mention "c/c++" since such a thing doesn't exist. As for the issue, pointers are just pointers and cannot be used as arrays. There's no size information. Just have to use them as pointers and give sizes with them to the functions if needed.

Comment: @SamerTufail I disagree on the duplicate suggestion: that is about initialization, here is about passing a reference as function argument.

Comment: the template you have works only for static arrays. As others have pointed out, in `int[size] x;` `x` is an array, while in `x = new int[SIZE];` `x` is a pointer

Comment: @user463035818 I see, that was quite illuminating. Thanks!

Comment: @SamerTufail thank you, although I cannot see where I am wrong in the array initialization

Comment: @artcorpse thank you. I can make the 1D case compile by using `sign(int* arr, int N, int i)`. But I cannot figure out the 2D case. It won't work with an `int**` arr as argument.

Comment: my apologies for being careless with your question, I am more attuned to `std::arrays` and `std::vectors` I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing the pointer to the array to your sign function.

```
template <size_t M, size_t N> 
int sign(int(*arr)[N], int i, int j)
{
    return (arr[i][j] >= 0) ? +1 : -1 ;
}
```

You can then call your sign function as follows:

```
std::cout << "sign 0 1: " << sign<SIZE, SIZE>(arr2d, 0, 1) << std::endl ;
```

Comment: I see. This is finally what I was looking for: it also let me use the same function if I pass a static array. Awesome!

Comment: Is there a way without using template, for cases where the size of the matrix is not known at compile time..?

Comment: @campa yes there is, that is another question :)